# Match count in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, hash

I have a hash with various keywords. Now, I want to find the count of these keywords in the string.

I just wrote some part of code with a foreach loop.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "The invitro experiments are conducted on human liver microsom. "
          . " These liver microsom can be cultured in rats.";

my %hash = (
    "human"     => 1,
    "liver"     => 1,
    "microsom"  => 1,
);

for my $nme (keys %hash){
        # Some code which I am not sure
}
```

Expected output: `human:1; liver:2; microsom:3`

Can someone help me in this?

Thanks

Comment: why microsom: 3? There seem to be only two occurrences of that in `$string`!

Comment: You should [try something](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) before asking. If you did, show us what you tried.

Comment: Sorry. It should be microsom:2.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet should suffice.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $string="The invitro experiments are conducted on human liver microsom. These liver   microsom can be cultured in rats.";

my %hash = (
'human' => 1,
'liver' => 1,
'microsom' => 1,
);

my @words = split /\b/, $string;

my %seen;

for (@words) {
    if ($_ eq 'human' or $_ eq 'liver' or $_ eq 'microsom') {
        $seen{$_}++;
    }
}

for (keys %hash) {
    print "$_: $seen{$_}\n";
}
```

Comment: Try `split /\b/, $string;` to split on word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Is that homework? :) Well, depends on number of words in hash, and number of words in string ( strings ), it will be better iterate over hash, or iterate over words in string(s), incrementing appropriate values when found. As you need to check all the words, you will end with a list with some marked "0" occurences, and some marked more than zero.

Answer (score 0):

probably not the best way of going about this, but it should work.

```
my $string = "The invitro experiments are conducted on human liver microsom. These liver microsom can be cultured in rats.";

my %hash = (
    'human' => 1,
    'liver' => 1,
    'microsom' => 1,
);

foreach my $nme (keys %hash){
    $hash{$nme} = scalar @{[$string =~ /$nme/g]};
    print "$hash{$nme}\n";
}
```